# Removing some items in Gridlayout Recyclerview leaves Empty spaces

Tags: java, android

I am trying to remove some Items from my Json Response in my recyclerview but when I do that an empty item spaces is being created in place of the removed item. This is happening only when I use gridlayout manager with recyclerview , if I use Linearlayout manager there are no empty spaces.

Below is my code:

```
 activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(5), true));
    activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

And for Removing items:

```
 if (!user.emailId.equals(clickedemail)){
                 viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                 viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.removeAllViews();
                 viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                 //viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
             }else {
                 viewHolder.bindUser(user, RecycFragment.this);
             }
```

When I use the blow code it's works fine.

```
        activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

`JsonParsing` code:

```
 private void initializeFirebase() {

    final Query refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_GARMENTS);
    refUsers.keepSynced(true);

    final List<UploadImage> uploadImageList = new ArrayList<>();
    refUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UploadImage uploadImage = messageSnapshot.getValue(UploadImage.class);

                uploadImageList.add(uploadImage);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UploadImage, ChatsItemHolder>(UploadImage.class, R.layout.recycitemfirebase,
            ChatsItemHolder.class, refUsers) {
        @Override
        public ChatsItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            adapterItemChatsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext()), viewType, parent, false);
            //adapterItemChatsBinding.tvUserName.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(getActivity(), Constants.FONT_ROBOT_REGULAR));

            return new ChatsItemHolder(adapterItemChatsBinding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ChatsItemHolder viewHolder, final UploadImage user, int position) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            clickedemail = prefs.getString(Constants.KEY_CLICKED_EMAIL, "");

             if (!user.emailId.equals(clickedemail)){
                 viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                 viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.removeAllViews();
                 viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

              //viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.gooot.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
             }else {
                 viewHolder.bindUser(user, RecycFragment.this);
             }

          viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.title.setText(user.getGarment_name());

            viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.count.setText(user.getGarment_color());
            Glide.with(viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.thumbnail.getContext())
                    .load(user.getImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .into(viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.thumbnail);
        }
    };

    activityRecylerviewBinding.recyclerview1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

}

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: refresh the adapter by using **notifyDataSetChanged()**


code as follows:

`activityRecylerviewBinding.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you removing your item from the dataset?

The action to remove the item should have the items index in the dataset should it not?  If so something like this should work:

```
public void removeItem(final int index) {
    list.remove(index);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that adapter for recyclerview is built with the the firebase query as the source of the items.

You need to change your firebase query to only fetch the items you want to have in your list.